# How can I aggregate averages from two models for use in one model's field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Review(models.Model):
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  album = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  rating = models.IntegerField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)],
    default=10,
  )
  content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  ...

class AddedReview(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  rating = models.IntegerField(default=10)
  body = models.TextField()
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  ...
```

The `Review` model is an initial review posted by a user. The `AddedReview` model is additional reviews users will be able to post on an initial `Review`
The initial `Review` will have a `rating` added by the original user, and additional `rating`s will be added by other users.
I want to be able to aggregate all the `rating`s from both models into an `avg_rating` field for use in the `Review` model.

I know how to perform this in a Python shell but I'm not very knowledgable about how to create a model method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)],
        default=10,
    )
    # [...]
  
    def give_avg_rev(self):
        rev = self.rating

        # maybe `.all()` in next line is not neccessary
        add_rev = self.addedreview_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        return (rev + add_rev) / 2

class AddedReview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    # [...]
```

Read more about [one-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships). When you have one `Review` hosting multiple `AddedReview`, you can say: One `Review` has a set of `AddedReview`s. This leads you to the reverse lookup functionality of django. Search on linked site for "_set" and you'll find more examples.

Since you did not tell where you want to use this functionality I'll show a basic view:

```py
def my_view(request):
    r = Review.objects.all().first()
    return HttpResponse(f"Average rating is {r.give_avg_rev()}")
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: The result of the functionality needs to be stored in a field inside the `Review` model (if that's possible) because all of the fields in the `Review` model are being displayed on my home page. For example: ```<h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'review' review.id %}">{{ review.artist }} - {{ review.album }}</a></h5>```

Comment: That is not a good Idea though. Because then you would need something like a signal when a new `AddedReview` is added and recalculate and update that field. When on one hand your template displays the "artist"-model-field like so: `{{ object.artist }}` on the other hand you can display the method "give_avg_rev" like so: `{{ object.give_avg_rev }}`. I really recommend to compute the average on the fly instead of storing it.